# Django - Saving one form multiple times

Tags: python, mysql, django, forms

I have a Django view that uses one form multiple times. The form is saving relationship Subgroup id as a foreign key and Student id as a foreign key .

The problem I'm having is when I try to save information to database it only saves the last record.

For example (database model):

```
 1       858 | Pump      | Iron 
 2        78 | Madagaskar| Thomas
```

And if Im trying to split them into seperate groups, only **Madagaskar** his data is saved:

```
  id | timestamp                  | student_Id_id | subgroup_Id_id |
+----+----------------------------+---------------+----------------+
| 62 | 2016-05-06 10:54:49.022000 |             2 |             91 |
```

The form looks like this:

```
class ApplicationFormaFull1(MultiModelForm):
    form_classes = {
        'sub1': FormSubgroup,
        'sub2': FormSubgroup,
        'stud_sub': FormStudent_in_Subgroup
    }
```

and my view :

```
sub = form['sub1'].save(commit=False)
sub.student_group = StudentGroup.objects.get(id=element)
sub.number = 1
sub.type = 'Other'
sub.student_count = firstSubgroup
sub.save()

sub1 = form['sub2'].save(commit=False)
sub1.student_group = StudentGroup.objects.get(id=element)
sub1.number = 2
sub1.type = 'Others'
sub1.student_count = secondSubgroup
sub1.save()

if (counter%2==1):
    stud_sub = form['stud_sub'].save(commit=True)
    stud_sub.subgroup_Id = sub
    stud_sub.student_Id = Student.objects.get(id=student)
    stud_sub.save()
else:
    stud_sub = form['stud_sub'].save(commit=True)
    stud_sub.subgroup_Id = sub1
    stud_sub.student_Id = Student.objects.get(id=student)
    stud_sub.save()
```

### So to sum up, I want that every form would save its information multiple times (dynamically)

Maybe the solution is that I should store information in the list and after all forms are added, save them one by one ?

```
stud_sub = form['stud_sub'].save(commit=False)
stud_sub.subgroup_Id = sub
stud_sub.student_Id = Student.objects.get(id=student)
list.add(stud_sub)
...
for i in list:
    i.save()
```

---

Other solution use formset:

```
ArticleFormSet = formset_factory(ArticleForm, extra=2)
formset = ArticleFormSet(initial=[
    {'title': 'Django is now open source',
      'pub_date': datetime.date.today(),}
 ])
```

However i dont know how to change title, pub_date and to add everyting to formset dynimically.

Comment: Why aren't you using a formset?

Comment: @DanielRoseman checkout edited